# Use the frequency vector to see which attribute is most common and make a score

Tags: php

I would like to use an algorithm to find out how many times an attribute that I offer appears and with what value it appears more often and to make a score on them (ie a counter that I display at the end how many times it appears)
Can I apply the frequency vector or is there something like that in laravel or php?

For example I have the following array

```
<?php
    $attributes = [
      'color' => ['red', 'red', 'red', 'blue', 'red']
      'height' => [2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 2, 2, 2, 2]
      'material' => ['iron', 'iron', 'gold', 'gold', 'gold'];
     ];
?>
```

In the end I would like to display something like this

```
'color' => 3
```

how many times an attribute appears but I would like to display the value that appears several times

```
‘Color’ = > [
   ‘count’ => 3, 
   ‘Red’ => 2,
   ‘Blue’ => 1
]
```

But still to be a top down with what appears several times, not just a value

I tried something like this

```
$attributes = (object)[
     $attribute = [
      'color' => ['red', 'red', 'red', 'blue', 'red']
      'height' => [2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 2, 2, 2, 2]
      'material' => ['iron', 'iron', 'gold', 'gold', 'gold']
     ];
  $array = [$attributes];
  
  $count = [];
  foreach ($array as $object) {
      if (isset($object->attribute)) {
          $attribute = $object->attribute;
          if (!isset($count[$attribute])) {
              $count[$attribute] = 0;
          }
          $count[$attribute]++;
      }
  }
  
  echo "<pre>";
  print_r($count);
```

Comment: What have you tried? This looks like a simple linear problem where you iterate through an array and implement some light custom logic to do counts (eventually using an aux array to store the results).

Comment: The keys need to be unique, you want to use something like `'color'=>['red','blue','green']` and then just select the one with the highest count

Comment: I would like to make a top with everything that appears in that key, it really has to be unique.
But how could I make a top with the values in the keys appear?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, like I showed in my previous comment by creating an object that contains `key` `array` pairs with the colors in an array under the key `color`  and the heights in an array with the key `height` and then count the amount of objects in each array for each key.